# Precedence of overlapping link annotations in PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

When the bounding boxes for multiple Link Annotations in PDF overlap, and the user clicks on the overlapped region, how is the activated link determined? And is it possible to force one annotation to have a higher precedence than another?

Answer (score 2):

The Z order for annotations is defined by the order they appear in page's /Annots array. The first annotation in the array is at the bottom, the last annotation in the array is at the top. 
This is the behavior I observed in Adobe Acrobat, I do not know if it is actually documented.
Changing the order of annotations in the /Annots array depends on the tool you use.

Comment: This is the behaviour I am seeing Acrobat, evince, and okular. But the chrome PDF viewer seems to stack the annotations in the opposite order.  i.e. The first annotation in the array is at the top. Is there any documentation I could use to support a bug request to chrome?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the precedence is in the order of creation. Annotations are stacked on top of each other, and the newer one is on top of the older one.

With fields, you do have a possibility to change the stacking order, by adjusting the tab order. This is, however, not possible with comments/annotations.